# Adding resource in Codedom compiled file VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, resources, codedom

I have tried searching for a solution but failed miserably. Can anyone please point me in the right direction to a solution? Reference to Codedom: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx

I am trying to add resource using:

```
Parameters.EmbeddedResources.Add(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\HTML.txt")
Parameters.EmbeddedResources.Add(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\logo.png")
```

But I can't access them from external source using:

```
 Dim content As String = My.Resources.HTML
 Dim logo As Image = My.Resources.logo
```

This is the error:

```
'Resource' is not memeber of 'My'.
'Resource' is not memeber of 'My'.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix the 'Resources' is not a member of 'My'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299768/how-to-fix-the-resources-is-not-a-member-of-my)

Comment: I am using Codedom to compile the file. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try: `(your namespace here).Properties.Resources.(resource here)` or use the [**ResourceManager class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The `My.Resources` namespace is something the VB IDE generates, it not part of NET or some some library you can add.  Open your resource designer file and you will see each resource property is just a wrapper for `ResourceManager.GetObject()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped and solved the problem. I'll try to answer my own question with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem:

**Compiler.vb**:

```
Using rw As New ResourceWriter(".\Library.resources")
   rw.AddResource("HTML.txt", My.Resources.HTML)
   rw.Generate()
   rw.Close()
End Using
Parameters.EmbeddedResources.Add(".\Library.resources")
```

**source.txt**:

```
Dim rm As New ResourceManager("Library", GetType(NameSpace).Assembly)
Dim SomeString As String = rm.GetString("HTML.txt")
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, in my case the resources are not a text file, they are `dll` file, and i need to create them using the function : `File.WriteAllBytes()`...., do you have any idea?